# Adobe AIR-Disable manually autostart app after install

Tags: air

I've a question in Adobe AIR Installation.
During install AIR Application, how we can disable Autostart checkbox mode?
I only want install app without click on checkbox to disabling this!
thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if will be possible to do it. You can follow this [conversation](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3064732).
I found some useful informations, and maybe will help you, you can check these [AIR application start-up options](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/quickstart/articles/startup_options.html) and [Distribute Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime-distribution1.html).